# node + html page load+ javascript, can't load main.js file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Really sorry for this stupid simple question, but I have tried to get this working for 20+ hours and I'm exhausted... Also searched/tried probably a 100+ ways to execute this.

I have a node server called **server.js**, html page called **index.html** and a javascript file called **main.js**.

I am trying to simply load the index.html-file on request (when loading http://localhost:2500/ ) and it works, but I just **can't get the damn main.js to load**... so it only prints what ever is on the index.html-file.

server.js-file:

```
var http=require('http');
var fs=require('fs');
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
// var path=require('path');

// app.use("/", express.static(__dirname));
// app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/public")));
app.use(express.static('public'));

//404 response
function send404response(response) {
    response.writeHead(404,{"Context-Type":"text/plain"});
    response.write("error 404:page not found");
    response.end();
}

//Handle user request
function onRequest(request,response) {

    if(request.method=='GET' && request.url =='/'){
        response.writeHead(200,{"Context-Type":"text/html"});
        fs.createReadStream("public/pages/index.html").pipe(response);
    }
    else {
        send404response(response);
    }
    }

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(2500);
console.log('server is running');
```

index.html-file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
href="main.css" /> -->

</head>
<body>ddfg

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js doesn't really contain anything worth linking. It works well without node being involved.

edit:
Forgot to include file structure.

server.js is on the root

public/js/main.js 
public/pages/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import javascript files in node you can do it by something like:

```
const myJsFunctions = require('./main.js');
```

then you can call your functions by something like `myJsFunctions.functionName()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. This already gave me new information. For some reason my server posts "Error: Cannot find module '.public/js/main.js'"

Comment: Thank you. I was missing that one "/" :)
Now i have completely new set of problems. Could you please tell me one more thing. Where should I call that "myJsFunctions.functionName()"

Comment: Now I understand what you meant. I think I'm looking for a different solution or there is none. I'm trying to load the entire body-content of index.html (<p>s, <div>s, texts, etc.) from the main.js.

Comment: Not sure if you can do that, doesnt seem like it makes much sense. Maybe check this, no reason to redirect to html page if you are using it just to load javascript http://ejs.co

Comment: I was kinda going in that ejs-direction, but now I will definitely do that. As you said. my solution probably doesn't make much sense.. :)